# How to set up Joomshopping Google Shopping/Yandex Market URL export from CLI?

Tags: php, url, joomla, joomla3.0

JShopping uses SEFLink function for pretty urls, but it seems to be incompatible with running from CLI. It throws "Application Instantiation Error".

So how can I get correct SEO friendly urls for a product from CLI?

Here is the entire Joomla cron without all the includes/requires above.
The crash happens at JFactory::getApplication() in SEFLink or if you get rid of that in getDefaultItemid().

```
class JshopProductExport extends JApplicationCli
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function doExecute()
    {
        if (!file_exists(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_jshopping/jshopping.php')){
            echo "Please install component \"joomshopping\"\n";
        }
        require_once (JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_jshopping/lib/factory.php'); 
        require_once (JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_jshopping/lib/functions.php');

        $sefLink = SEFLink('index.php?option=com_jshopping&controller=product&task=view&category_id=1&product_id=1', 0, 0, null);
    }
}

try
{
    JApplicationCli::getInstance('JshopProductExport')->execute();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    var_dump($e);
    exit($e->getCode());
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the commands and/or the code that you trying to execute?

Comment: @Webdesigner I apologize, I should've done that from the beginning. Updated the question.